# android different interval variables

Tags: android, variables, broadcast

How can I get broadcast methods variables?

There is only a variable in broadcast. Here is my part of code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
       setContentView(R.layout.main);  
       //I want to use a in here like textview.settext(a);
             IntentFilter intent = new IntentFilter();  
             registerReceiver(searchDevices, intent);
     }  
     private BroadcastReceiver searchDevices = new BroadcastReceiver() {      
     public void onReceive(Context context,  Intent intent) {  
               int a=0;
      }
     }
```

Comment: What do you mean "get broadcast methods variables"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put parcelable variables to Intent instance:

```
Intent i = new intent();
i.putExtra("a", 0);
```

Then in your receiver code you get values:

```
int a = i.getIntExtra("a");
```

[This document might be helpful.](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/index.html)